# Why subtraction of more than 30 days resulting wrong answer

Tags: java, datetime

If I try to subtract 1 to 29 days the return date is correct but if I try to subtract more than 30 days the return date is wrong. Can anybody explain where I'm going wrong?

```
public class MapTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date dNow = new Date( );
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-dd-MM");

        try {
            Date date = ft.parse("2011-01-10");
            Date su=new Date(date.getTime()-30*24*3600*1000);
            System.out.println(su);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What output you're getting, and what you expected?

Comment: What did you find when you stepped through the code in your debugger?

Comment: use  30*24*3600*1000L

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman thanks a lot..yes it worked now...btw why we need to add L what exactly it doing

Comment: @user1742919 it forces type of numeric constant to long

Comment: Alternatively this is more clear `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1) * 30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Date constructor is expecting a long value.  The code works if you specify long values:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MapTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date dNow = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM");

        try {
            Date date = ft.parse("2011-01-10");
            Date su = new Date(date.getTime() - 30L * 24L * 3600L * 1000L);
            System.out.println(su);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats the Best explanation of the Day....Constructor expecting long...hmm...okay i got it now

Answer (score 8):

You have overflow in int constant: 30*24*3600*1000.

Try to cast ints to long:
`Date su=new Date(date.getTime() - 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000L);`

Comment: I find it's easier to distinguish if you use a capital L instead of lower case. It's easy to mistake `30l` for `301`, not so with `30L`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of Integer underflow/overflow.

When a integer goes too high, it will go from positive to negative.

Example of this:

```
System.out.println(24*24*3600*1000); // = 2073600000
System.out.println(25*24*3600*1000); // = -2134967296
```

When the we celebrated the new millennium ,people were also scared for this when their 99 went overflowing to 00.

To fix this problem, you could cast 1 of the numbers to a Long by `30l*24*3600*1000`.

Answer (score 2):

As @antonu17 mentioned, you are having overflow error.

If you want date before or after than you can directly do that calculations on calendar object.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (-/+)30); //you can add - sign to 30 if you want current date -30 days.
```

Then get date from this calendar object.

Comment: yes but i personally feel till it can be done using inbuilt classes why to use for third party libraries or api.